# How do you pass variable to callback function?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, asynchronous, callback

New to node, express, and javascript.

Below is code in my `index.js` in `routers`folder.

I want to pass along or access `res` variable in `handleImport` function.

```
function handleImport( err, stat)
{
  if(err == null) {
    // Do something with res
    res.end();
  }
  else{
    // Do something with res
    res.end();
  }
}


router.get('/traveler', function(req, res, next) {
    var import_path = req.query.drawing;
    fs.stat(import_path,handleImport);
});
```

It appears bind() may be what I'm after but cannot find a good source for how to use it correctly.

Comment: You need to pass context via the function parameters to the handleImport function

Comment: @simon-p-r How do I change function parameters when fs.stat already has a prototype defined that it requires?  I have a feeling there is something simple I am missing.

Comment: You can wrap the fs.stat function, answer below is valid however if your handler is already bloated write a function in separate file with the signature you require and call function to handle the request.  There are many solutions to this problem, bind won't help you in this example.

Comment: @simon-p-r Thanks for the help.  I got that to work.  It feels messy.  I may just write some C code instead.  Problem doesn't fit well into this framework.

Comment: No worries I wish I could write c as well as javascript!

Answer (score 0):

AFAICS, the best solution is to use anonymous function.

```
router.get('/traveler', function(req, res, next) {
    var import_path = req.query.drawing;

    fs.stat(import_path, function (err, stat) {
        if (err == null) {
            // Do something with res
            res.end();
        } else {
            // Do something with res
            res.end();
        }
    });
});
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/name

Comment: Well I have working code that looks like that already.  The problem is its grown into a giant mess.